# Magento2: How to add a small Icon image on product image in product view page in magento 2

Tags: template, product-images, magento2.2.2

I wish to add small icon image on the product image in magento 2.

- From which template the product image is loaded in product view page.
  Please provide me a solution.

Comment: You want that image, on Product detail's page only right ?

Comment: if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark , hit that tickmark for right ansewer that will help future readers.

Comment: Yes I want it in Product Details page @Aditya Shah

Comment: I need the exact template file to add my image icon, If you have an idea Please suggest me

Comment: Yes, got you !!

Comment: But can you please tell me where exactly you want to show that icon ? I mean where In product Image ? Above below or on Product image ?

Comment: On the Right  side  corner of the product image

Comment: Have you tried the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create media image attribute From admin menu, `Stores > Attributes > product.`

2) Get this attribute to your file.

```
<?php
$_product  = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);  
$attrImage = $_product->getData('my_logo');   

if(isset($attrImage) && $attrImage != 'no_selection' ){
    $productImageAttr = $product->getCustomAttribute( 'my_logo' );
    $productImage     = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product, 'my_logo')->setImageFile($productImageAttr->getValue());?>
<img src="<?php echo $productImage->getUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($product->getTitle()) ?>" />
<?php }?>
```

Comment: In Which template is responsible to add my icon image to display on product image

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/set-custom-image-role-for-product-in-magento-2-507) will work for you, Just add image tag to display `custom attribute` in **product listing** page.

- From this you can add attribute name you want to create as They have given Diamond icons and then select Catalog Input Type as Media image. Now save the attribute.

Let me know if if you have any query.